Serial killer who is a photographer
I'm looking for either a movie or a tv show involving a pair of detectives who investigated a series of murders. I want to say that the victims were mostly females. After a while, the detectives realized that the killer must have been a photographer because the latter had posted such photos about the crime scenes that no one besides the police and the killer could have access to.
The film/tv show was from the West and the language was either English or French.
Edit: I saw this in the late 90's or early 2000's. The photos were posted in a newspaper.
Edit 2: I dont remember how the murders were committed except for that the crime scenes were striking hence photo-worthy. What I do remember is that in their investigation, the detectives had run into the photographer long before they made the deduction that he committed the crimes.

Do you remember the approximate year? And where did the photographer publish the pictures? (In a newspaper? The web? An art gallery?)

How were the women killed?

Your description reminds of an episode of The X-Files called "Tithonus", which aired in January of 1999.
Here's an episode description: 

Agent Scully gets paired up with a new partner to investigate a
  singular case. Alfred Fellig, a freelance crime photographer, has a
  knack for arriving at crime scenes shortly after the murder and long
  before the police arrive. Local authorities suspect Fellig may be
  killing the victims himself before photographing them.


This is the one. My memories weren't accurate but you managed to find it. Thanks a lot!

I'm a bit of a fan of the show (though I didn't start watching till after it ended- I was 6 when it started) and that episode is one that I remember especially because Scully almost becomes one of his victims.
